# Expand to blank with unnest

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, purrr

I find [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) *SUPER* useful for making results tables for a bunch of different variables. I was wondering if there was a way for the `unnest()` function (or otherwise) to expand a high order variable into blanks, rather than just repeating.

For example, with this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(
  group1 = sample(c('dog','cat', 'gecko'), 100, replace = T),
  group2 = sample(c('hot dog', 'not hotdog', 'other'), 100, replace = T)
)

my_freq <- function(var){
  result <- as.data.frame(table(data[[var]]))
  colnames(result) <- c('level', 'n')
  return(result)
}

the_table <- data.frame(var = c('group1', 'group2'))
the_table <- the_table %>% 
  mutate(
    result = map(var, my_freq)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(result)
```

Instead of the resulting table looking like:

[image]

It would look like this:

[image]

I guess this would be a multi-level index in [python](/questions/tagged/python), but not sure how to accomplish in [r](/questions/tagged/r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by blank (in this example I am going with `NA`). The critical line is:

```r
mutate(var = if_else(!duplicated(var), var, NA_integer_))
```

Minimal working example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(
  group1 = sample(c('dog','cat', 'gecko'), 100, replace = T),
  group2 = sample(c('hot dog', 'not hotdog', 'other'), 100, replace = T)
)

my_freq <- function(var){
  result <- as.data.frame(table(data[[var]]))
  colnames(result) <- c('level', 'n')
  return(result)
}

the_table <- data.frame(var = c('group1', 'group2'))
the_table <- the_table %>% 
  mutate(
    result = map(var, my_freq)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(result) %>%
  mutate(var = if_else(!duplicated(var), var, NA_integer_))

the_table
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   var    level          n
#>   <fct>  <fct>      <int>
#> 1 group1 cat           38
#> 2 <NA>   dog           38
#> 3 <NA>   gecko         24
#> 4 group2 hot dog       36
#> 5 <NA>   not hotdog    34
#> 6 <NA>   other         30
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Right, NAs would serve as good blanks. Nifty trick. But what about higher order variables that would go alongside this example of "var," such as degrees freedom which could be duplicated naturally but should be shown at each higher level?

Answer (score 1):

Extending rmagno's solution to other high order variables

```
...%>%
  mutate_at(
    .vars = vars(high_order_vars),
    .funs = function(x) ifelse(duplicated(.[['var']]), NA, x)
  )
```

Comment: plus one for generalising my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an `lapply` to get a list I call `tb` of the two tables. Then create a `matrix` with `names(tb)` in the first row and the rest blanks and convert it to a data frame. Finally `Map` assigns the desired names applying `cbind` on the columns of both data frames consecutively.

```
tb <- lapply(data, function(x) setNames(as.data.frame(table(x)), c("level", "n")))
res <- do.call(rbind, 
               Map(cbind, 
                   var=data.frame(
                     matrix(c(names(tb), rep("", (el(lapply(tb, nrow)) - 1)*2)),
                            ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)), 
                   tb))
res
#         var      level  n
# X1.1 group1        cat 31
# X1.2               dog 26
# X1.3             gecko 43
# X2.1 group2    hot dog 35
# X2.2        not hotdog 37
# X2.3             other 28
```